# Should Google's uid be stored in a Varchar or Decimal column in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, google-oauth, google-signin

With Google user ID bigger than BigInt, what should one use to store Google user ID in Varchar or Decimal?

Comment: This depends mainly on how you want to use it. VARCHAR would be my choice probably. If you use it for sorting, joining, filtering heavily and with millions of rows - think twice...

Comment: I will be doing a lot of where uid = x on every sign-in, after ID Token is sent to google for validation.  Varchar shouldn't be too bad, but Decimal seems like a good choice if it's more efficient, but I don't know if Google user ID will go above 38 digits (max digits supported by Decimal).

Comment: You could think of splitting the number into two BIGINTs and create all keys on both... This should be faster than VARCHAR and will not run out of digits soon...

Comment: @Shugo interesting, never thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

made an answer out of that, to have some more space... In an old project, it was before the GUIDs, I had to deal with a wide spread application where users were allowed to enter data disconnectedly. We thought a lot about the "how to" and desided to split the existing INT-id in a low-word (entryID) and a high-word (userID). This range was sufficient... Worked like a charm...

So: give the double BIGINT-Key a try. this will be lightning fast - especially in an 64bit environment.

Comment: Unless the Google UID is logically two different pieces of information, place it in a single column with an appropriate type.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance, But there is no appropriate type! That is the point of this question... Look at the OP's points and badges. This question is obviously not a question of simple db theory... I suggested a creative approach. If you have a better one, just post your answer!

Comment: Like the idea of double-BigInt, because numbers are always fastest. In implementation, I face this, if `100930867628408514795` to be split at 13th position from left, i.e. right after **...284**. `1009308676284` will be intact, **08514795** will lose its leading zero to be **8514795**. And in real life, not easy to predict how many consecutive zeros in the middle. Can you shed some light on how to make it _a low-word (entryID) and a high-word (userID)_? Thank you.

Comment: @Jeb50 we did not concatenate numbers, but used an int but *interpreted* this on binary level. You actually split on byte level